# How to print php info inside <a> tags, etc?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to print php variables inside a HTML tag?

Like this:

```
<?php
for ($e = 1; $e <= 30; $e++) {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    print ('<div id="map"><a>$i</a></div>');  // <----I'm adding the divs here, but I want to add a text inside each of them
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case take the variable out of the string and concatenate it inside.

```
print ('<div id="map"><a>'.$i.'</a></div>');
```

This is pretty basic stuff so I suggest you go through some tutorials or read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) again.

Comment: it did the trick!
I don't use php often, so this kind of thigs are totally out of my mind ! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your call:

```
echo '<a href="'.$href.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

or

```
echo "<a href='$href'>$title</a>";
```

or

```
<a href="<?= $href ?>"><?= $title ?></a>
```

I prefer the first one, because I think it is the most readable. But it is up to you.

Using your example:

```
print ('<div id="map"><a>'.$i.'</a></div>');
```

or

```
print ("<div id=\"map\"><a>$i</a></div>"); // note the double quotes to allow PHP to parse the string
```

or

```
<div id="map"><a><?= $i ?></a></div> // but you really should do this!
```

To better clarify you SHOULD NEVER rely on short tags (the last option). Every time you do that god will kill a kitten and abuse a unicorn.

Comment: with short_open_tag = "1" for this last one.

Comment: @LucLaverdure what do you mean? Did I screw something up? :P

Comment: Isn't it faster to do `echo '<a href="', $href, '">', $title, '</a>';`? I don't remember, but I thought I read an article on that.

Comment: @animuson actually it is faster, but it is by convention that I never use it. And the performance gain is really small. Nice comment though!

Comment: No you didn't mess up anything, everything is fine, but you need short_open_tag = "1" in php settings or it will fail to load <? ?> instead of <?php ?> ;)

Comment: @LucLaverdure ah right. Well that's basically the reason for the comment about not using it. I will add it to the question just to be sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what text you want to add there, you can have any other variables in there, same how you're printing the $i .. except that single quotes do not evaluate variables inside the string, only double quotes do ..

so:

```
$foo = "bar";
print "$foo"  => "bar"
print '$foo'  => "$foo"
```

Comment: Thanks guys for all the support!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='<?php echo "http://www.stackoverflow.com"; ?>' target='_blank'>test</a> (Syntax maybe off)
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php
for ($e = 1; $e <= 30; $e++) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++) {
        print ('<div id="map"><a>'. $i .'</a></div>');
    }
}
?>
```

Note the **'. $i .'** part.

Comment: Why are you concatenating JavaScript style?

Comment: Ah thx, Code is updated. :) Because I use ~5 different languages everyday and I'm easily confused :P

Answer (score 0):

You're using single quotes to output your variable. using double quotes may work instead, but I prefer using string concatenation(. operator)

```
print ("<div id=\"map\"><a>$i</a></div>");
```

Or

```
print ('<div id="map"><a>' . $i . '</a></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"` instead of `'` when you want to use variables in a string.